# Error: "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection." using EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to recreate [MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1) but I've faced an error which I can't handle: "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection". The error is related to the following line in the ShoppingCart Index view:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Product.Title, "Details", "Store", new { id = item.ProductId }, null)
```

ShoppingCartController:

```
public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
    {
        OnlineStoreDbContext db = new OnlineStoreDbContext();

        //
        // GET: /ShoppingCart/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
            {
                CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
                CartTotal = cart.GetTotal()
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Store/AddToCart/5

        public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
        {
            // Retrieve the album from the database
            var addedProduct = db.Products.Single(product => product.ProductId == id);

            // Add it to the shopping cart
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            cart.AddToCart(addedProduct);

            // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RemoveFromCart(int id)
        {
            // Remove the item from the cart
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            // Get the name of the album to display confirmation
            string productName = db.Carts.Single(item => item.RecordId == id).Product.Title;

            // Remove from cart
            int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);

            // Display the confirmation message
            var results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
            {
                Message = Server.HtmlEncode(productName) + " has been removed from your shopping cart.",
                CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
                ItemCount = itemCount,
                DeleteId = id
            };

            return Json(results);
        }

        //
        // GET: /ShoppingCart/CartSummary

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult CartSummary()
        {
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            ViewData["CartCount"] = cart.GetCount();

            return PartialView("CartSummary");  
        }
    }
```

ShoppingCart Index View:

```
@model OnlineStoreMVC.UI.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
}
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
        $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
            // Get the id from the link
            var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");

            if (recordToDelete != '') {

                // Perform the ajax post
                $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart", { "id": recordToDelete },
                    function (data) {
                        // Successful requests get here
                        // Update the page elements
                        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                            $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                        } else {
                            $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
                        }

                        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                    });
            }
        });

    });


    function handleUpdate() {
        // Load and deserialize the returned JSON data
        var json = context.get_data();
        var data = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(json);

        // Update the page elements
        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
            $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
        } else {
            $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
        }

        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
    }
</script>

<h3>
    <em>Review</em> your cart:
</h3>
<p class="button">
    @Html.ActionLink("Checkout", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")
</p>
<div id="update-message">
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Movie Title
        </th>
        <th>
            Price (each)
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantity
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
    {
        <tr id="row-@item.RecordId">
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Product.Title, "Details", "Store", new { id = item.ProductId }, null)
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Product.Price
            </td>
            <td id="item-count-@item.RecordId">
                @item.Count
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.RecordId">Remove from cart</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    <tr>
        <td>
            Total
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="cart-total">
            @Model.CartTotal
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit:**

```
public class ShoppingCart
    {
        string ShoppingCartId { get; set; }

        public const string CartSessionKey = "CartId";

        public static ShoppingCart GetCart(HttpContextBase context)
        {
            var cart = new ShoppingCart();
            cart.ShoppingCartId = cart.GetCartId(context);
            return cart;
        }

        public static ShoppingCart GetCart(Controller controller)
        {
            return GetCart(controller.HttpContext);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This error means pretty much exactly what it says. Somewhere, you've disposed of your application context instance, and then tried to make another query with it. This happens frequently when you're misusing lazy loading and perhaps being a little over-eager with disposing your context (wrapping it in a `using` block) for example.

I'm not seeing any likely culprit in the code you posted but `ShoppingCart.GetCart` looks like a prime candidate for further investigation.

Basically, you want to do two things. First, you want to get a handle on what's actually being utilized by your action/views. If you're accessing related items to a cart, or something, then you should consider eager-loading those with `Include`. Second, you need to ensure that you context sticks around throughout the period it needs to be used. If you're lazy loading items in your view, *and* you intend to do that, then you'll need to make it last the life of the request: just don't use `using` and rely on the `Dispose` method of the controller for disposing of it.

That's generalized advice though. Since I believe your issue lies in this `GetCart` method, if that's actually the case, then you need to approach it slightly differently. First, you can ensure that `GetCart` returns a fully-baked result, that will not allow further querying. In cases where you're returning an enumerable, you can normally clear this up just by using `.AsList()`. Since this is likely just returning a single object, you would need to map it to a DTO or something: anything other than the actual entity class.

Your other option is to inject your context to the method. Normally, injecting into the class would be preferred, but it looks like you're dealing with a static class here. Basically, you want to allow your controller to create and dispose the context and then just pass it as a parameter to your `GetCart` method, so that it uses the context in the controller instead of creating its own. Depending on your applications needs, you might actually consider implementing some dependency injection framework to handle tasks like these.

Comment: It's not about whether you're returning an "expected" result. What you need to look for is places later on in your code where you're trying to access some related item or items off of the cart object that weren't load in with the initial query.